# Change and move timestamp in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a document that is composed of a series of lines. In the middle of each line there is timestamp of the form `yy.mm.dd`, e.g. `15.12.05`.

Using PCRE (Perl compatible regular expressions) in Notepad++, how do I do the following?

1. Move each timestamp from the middle of its line to the end of its line.
2. Change the format of each timestamp from `yy.mm.dd` to `mmm dd, yyyy`, e.g. `Dec 05, 2015`.

Comment: Okay, have you tried something yet? What problems did you have which prompted you to ask here?

Comment: I didn't tried anything to success my mission. All my tries failed. I've searched some other topics. But all answers didn't do what i need.

Comment: What language / tool are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change date format in notepad++](//stackoverflow.com/q/41111579)

Comment: @4castle Ok.  Thank you.

Comment: @VladislavBickov If my answer solves your questions, then please make sure to upvote it as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three parts to this question.

1. How to extract a timestamp of the format `yy.mm.dd` from every line.
2. How to move said timestamp to the end of the line.
3. How to change the format of the timestamp.

## 1. Extracting the Timestamp

The timestamp format `yy.mm.dd` can be matched by this regex:

```
\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}
```

If every timestamp can be assumed to be proceeded and followed by non-words, then this regex will be even better:

```
\b\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}\b
```

## 2. Moving the Timestamp

In order to move the timestamp to the end of the line using find/replace, you will need to match the timestamp and the rest of the content of the line in separate groups.  (the following assumes there is exactly one timestamp per line)

```
Find:     ^(?<begin>.*?)(?<timestamp>\b\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}\b)(?<end>[^$]*)$
Replace:  \k<begin>\k<end> \k<timestamp>
```

## 3. Formatting the Timestamp

You should format the timestamps in a separate operation after you extract and move them.  This is because you will need to do 12 separate find/replace operations to correctly convert the timestamp formats, once for each month.

```
   Find:     (?<year>\d{2})\.01\.(?<day>\d{2})$
   Replace:  Jan \k<day>, 20\k<year>

   Find:     (?<year>\d{2})\.02\.(?<day>\d{2})$
   Replace:  Feb \k<day>, 20\k<year>

   ...

   Find:     (?<year>\d{2})\.12\.(?<day>\d{2})$
   Replace:  Dec \k<day>, 20\k<year>
```

*Note that this assumes every year is >= 2000.*